# Great emphasis is placed on education - OR - Great emphasis was placed on education

Tags: verbs, passive-voice

> Great emphasis is placed on education.

Sentence quoted from https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/place_2.

Why use 'is' and not 'was'? I confused because my understanding is that 'placed' is a past tense, and should use 'was'. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

In your sentence, **placed** is not a past-tense verb, it's a [past participle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Past_participle). It is part of a **[passive voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice)** construction.

Active-voice-construction:

> Someone places great emphasis on education. (Present)
>   Someone placed great emphasis on education. (Past)

Present-time passive voice construction:

> Great emphasis is placed on education.

Past-time passive voice construction:

> Great emphasis was placed on education.